# How to Display a spinner with Hidden Values

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley, spinner

In my App I Have a few Spinners populated with JSON data

this app is for logging work hours

So the Thing what i am struggling with is that one of the spinners has to display a diffrent value than what is passed to the URL for posting

So basically the Spinner displays 3 items like this

Example of 1 item,

```
UserID - UserRate - Value
```

So it looks like this in the spinner

```
7 - 1 - $200
```

this entire string is 1 Json Object in array

I use the userID and the second number server side to post the information to a table to log the hours
So I just want to display the $200 in the spinner dropdown but pass the entire line to the URL for posting

Code for populating the spinner

```
 private void LoadUserRatesSpinnerData(String url) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");
                        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String rates=jsonObject1.getString("UserRate");
                            UserRate.add(rates);
                        }
                    }
                    UserRatesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(IntTimeLog.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, UserRate));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout=30000;
        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: struggling with that  the spinner has to display a diffrent value than what is passed to the URL for posting, so it displays 7 - 1 - $200 now but I want to to display only the $200 but the backend value stays 7-1-$200 I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: is this "7 - 1 - $200" represent a single spinner item? and Will all the items in spinner be in same format

Comment: Yes that is one single spinner Item, All the items will be exactly the same although the first number ie 7 might be a double digit number like 11, the first number is a USERID pulled from the server so it has a max of 2 digits the second number is a number for the server to know witch one is selected and the $ is the value

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: Just tried to make it work for about an hour, Nothing suggested has worked so far

Comment: I got It working in a way now the resulting items in the spinner now look like this      [7 , 1 , $200]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203098/discussion-between-sandeep-dhiman-and-ruben-meiring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually use RegX to format this text while showing in Spinner, 
Your REGX may look something like this

```
final String str = "7 - 1 - $200";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("$").matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(str.substring(matcher.end()).trim()); //This should give you 200
}
```

Comment: So with this how can I then pass the Original value to a string for like Uploading purposes etc?

Comment: You should keep this in a separate string, while sending the data you should take the actual value which was there. If you want the complete solution, i may need you complete code where you are setting the text

Comment: Your code only gives for static strings I populate the spinner dynamically with JSON

Comment: i see this in your code  String rates=jsonObject1.getString("UserRate"); you should ideally replace this with  rates = rates .substring(matcher.end()).trim()

Comment: String rates=jsonObject1.getString("UserRate");  is for parsing th JSON this will result in a blank

Comment: i meant String rates=jsonObject1.getString("UserRate");  and in the next line rates = rates .substring(matcher.end()).trim()

Comment: I used your answer as a backbone for my own code to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same like this

```
 yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String value = yourList.get(position);
          String[]array = value.split("-")
          String yourValue = array[2].trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I am asking to use this answer Ruben

Comment: I got It working in a way now the resulting items in the spinner now look like this [7 , 1 , $200]

Comment: do you want to show only the last one($200) in your spinner ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Vinay's Answer I have edited it and got it working
I added a For Loop and edited the matcher

```
  for(int p=0; p < 100; p++){
                            final Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(" - ").matcher(rates);
                            if (matcher.find()) {
                                rates =rates.substring(matcher.end()).trim();
```